# No output information about audio cdrom in Python using cdparanoia

Tags: python, subprocess, raspberry-pi4

I am developing two simple Python applications for my spouse (on a Raspberry Pi 4+ with 7" touch screen).
The internet radio is still working stable and fine.

Now it's time to append an app for her old audio cd collections.
But until today I cannot solve this problem.

I want to know how many tracks are on it, so that I can select one to play.

My last hope was to do it with a shell command. Of course, the command works nicely in a UNIX environment, but not in Python.
And I do not understand what mistake I made. Could it be a problem of the `.decode('UTF-8')` method? Me surprises, that some seconds after command_2 was executed the cdrom starts to run for some seconds. But the same behavior using the command in the command line. During the commands it is quite.

If there was anyone with a helpful idea/solution or could tell me what misunderstanding I have, this would be genuinely nice.

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE

command_1 = ("ls", "-l")
result = subprocess.run(command_1, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
out = result.stdout
err = result.stderr

for line in out.decode('utf-8').splitlines():
    print("Result", line)

# up to here everything works nice as expected

# trying to run my favorite, I come into trouble
command_2 = ["cdparanoia", "-sQ"]
result = subprocess.run(command_2, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
out = result.stdout
err = result.stderr

for line in out.decode('utf-8').splitlines():
    print("Result", line)
```

Output of command_1 is the well-known example you will find everywhere.

Output of command_2

```
/home/pi/PycharmProjects/cd/venv/bin/python /home/pi/PycharmProjects/cd/cdrom.py

Process finished with exit code 0
```

That looks not very informative for me.

Running command_2 in a command line shows, what I would have expected:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cdparanoia -sQ
cdparanoia III release 10.2 (September 11, 2008)

Table of contents (audio tracks only):
track        length               begin        copy pre ch
===========================================================
  1.    22190 [04:55.65]       55 [00:00.55]    no   no  2
  2.    11350 [02:31.25]    22245 [04:56.45]    no   no  2
  3.    20567 [04:34.17]    33595 [07:27.70]    no   no  2
  4.    23500 [05:13.25]    54162 [12:02.12]    no   no  2
  5.    16985 [03:46.35]    77662 [17:15.37]    no   no  2
  6.    27358 [06:04.58]    94647 [21:01.72]    no   no  2
  7.    15880 [03:31.55]   122005 [27:06.55]    no   no  2
  8.    38797 [08:37.22]   137885 [30:38.35]    no   no  2
  9.    11043 [02:27.18]   176682 [39:15.57]    no   no  2
TOTAL  187670 [41:42.20]    (audio only)

pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

To get ahead of the question:

```
cdparanoia -sQ > file.txt
```

does not work, not even on the command line. Maybe there is a reason for the name of the command cdPARANOIA?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem.
I did not realize that the color of the output screen was **RED**. Red is an indicator of errors in PyCharm. ***That gave me the idea, that this could be an error output.***
Next step, I used the following command on the command line: `cdparanoia -Q 2>&1 | tee /home/pi/toc.txt`. That results in a text file that I now can use for further programming. Maybe this could be helpful for any other cdrom enthusiasts.
Here my test file for further informations:

```
import os

test = 4

if test == 1:      # RED text
    command = "cdparanoia -Q"

elif test == 2:    # WHITE text
    command = "cdparanoia -Q 2>&1"

elif test == 3:    # WHITE text, but no text file, the output needs to be doubled
    command = "cdparanoia -Q 2>&1 /home/pi/toc.txt"

elif test == 4:    # WHITE text and a textfile
    command = "cdparanoia -Q 2>&1 | tee /home/pi/toc.txt"

print("Test ", test, os.system(command))
```